# PS7 Loads WinForms Form Differently than PS5.1

Tags: powershell, winforms

If you run the following code in 5.1, it works.  But when you run it in 7.3.7, the `TopMost` setting is lost and the form will no longer stay on top of other windows.  But, if you uncomment the line in the Load event, it will work fine in 7.3.7.

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$MainForm = [Form]@{
    ClientSize          = '457, 45'
    Name                = 'MainForm'
    StartPosition       = 'CenterScreen'
    Text                = 'My Window'
    TopMost             = $true
}
$MainForm.Add_Load(
    {
        #$MainForm.TopMost = $true
    }
)
$null = $MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

I would think this is a known issue, but I'm not finding any documentation.  And, since I don't understand the cause, I'm concerned about what other settings are getting lost.

Does anyone know why this is happening and/or a way to prevent it?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255454/discussion-on-question-by-darin-ps7-loads-winforms-form-differently-than-ps5-1); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.